# is there pyqt4 reference documentation for python example?

Tags: python, reference, pyqt4

Is there a site like [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/modelview.html) with python example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PySide project is highly compatible with PyQT at the code level. It's documentation has (I think) all the examples from the C++ docs translated into reasonably idiomatic Python.

http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/contents.html

Unfortunately they haven't translated that particular tutorial, but if you look at some of the C++ examples alongside their PyQT/PySide equivalents you'll soon learn how to implement the C++ examples in Python. It's not that hard. I only know the very basics of C++ at a theoretical level, but got used to it fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of tutorials for PyQt around. But to my knowledge, none as comprehensive as the official docs. That said, all C++ Qt examples are very easy to translate to PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

You may look here: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/modules.html.

This is the official documentation converted to python. Some of the code there is still C++, but it's very easy to translate to PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

for now, jul 22

this is a valid URL for pyQt4 docs: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/